# Dynamically change min/max values for jquery-tools range input

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I'm using the new rangeInput in the jquery tools package for a slider. It's working, but my problem is I need to change it to english or metric units based on user preference and this is after the DOM has been loaded.

So I need to be able to set the max to 5000 or 465 based on what measurement system the user chooses. I've changed the values in the dom successfully, but it doesn't seem to affect the slider values.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the max/min values doesn't affect the value of the slider. You also need the convert the value of the slider to the unit system you use.

Comment: Changing the min max values SHOULD affect the slider because with square feet, the min/max is 1000/5000. With square meters the values become 93/465, changing the value of the slider isn't the biggest deal… it's changing the constraints of the slider.